# How to link a item in list widget to a radio button in a form in qt designer?

Tags: python

Actually I am creating a Fantasy Cricket game. There I need to calculate the points of the players. The points distribution sample is given. But there a problem raised: even after defining the variable "point", there came a NameError which said that the variable "point" is not defined.

My code and its bug:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of codes and error messages. [Post them as text.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You seem to have incorrectly indented code. Should the lines from `point=point+0.5*runs` up to the last `if` be part of the `def batting` method? If so, they should be indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

You define point but not it type and value. Add value by this way

```
def batting(runs, balls, p):
    point = p
    '''continue your code'''
```